# Custom UITableViewCell + resignFirstResponder

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, custom-cell

I have a `UITableView` with two `Custom Cells`. One of the `Custom Cells` contains a `UITextField`.

I'm having problems with hiding the keyboard when the return button is pressed.

```
- (IBAction)textFieldDoneEditing:(id)sender {
     [sender resignFirstResponder];
  }
```

Normally I would use this, but it get's never called. I connected it with the `Editing Did End` Event.

Is is because I use a `Custom Cell` ?

Comment: Have you set the text field delegate? And the method is called textFieldDidEndEditing:

Comment: Yes. I set the delegate of the text field. And I guess that's why it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to wire up an IBAction.  Use the delegate method (I also change my return key in IB to Done to make it more apparent to the user).  Make sure you have connected the delegate for the textfield to your VC class.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    // Dismiss the keyboard when the Return key is pressed.
    [textField resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```